# Create user Login / Registration Error (Angular, Ionic and Firebase)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

// Enviroment

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

export const environment = {
  production: false
};

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "SUS",
  authDomain: "SUS",
  projectId: "SUS",
  storageBucket: "Sus",
  messagingSenderId: "Sus",
  appId: "Sus",
  measurementId: "Sus"
};



// Initialize Firebase
const firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(firebase);

// Initialize Firebase Authentication and get a reference to the service
const auth = getAuth(firebase);

/*
 * For easier debugging in development mode, you can import the following file
 * to ignore zone related error stack frames such as `zone.run`, `zoneDelegate.invokeTask`.
 *
 * This import should be commented out in production mode because it will have a negative impact
 * on performance if an error is thrown.
 */
// import 'zone.js/plugins/zone-error';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

// signup.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.page.scss'],
})
export class SignupPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) { }
  gotologin() {
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('login');
  }
  SignUp() {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in 
        const user = userCredential.user;
        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // ..
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

// signup.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Sign Up</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ion-item lines="none">
    <ion-label position="floating">Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Firstname Lastname"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item lines="none">
    <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Email"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item lines="none">
    <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-button (click)="SignUp()">Sign In</ion-button>
</div>
<ion-content>

</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <div class="text" (click)="gotologin()">
    Already a Member? Sign In
  </div>
</ion-footer>
```

**ERROR**

```
ERROR

src/app/signup/signup.page.ts:19:42 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'email'.

19     createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
                                            ~~~~~


ERROR

src/app/signup/signup.page.ts:19:49 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'password'.

19     createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
                                                   ~~~~~~~~
```

I created a tabs ionic framework and created the pages login and signup now i want to have the signup page popup when there isnt a session cookie but my signup doesnt work.
I want to create a login and registration function for my notepad app. But I get an error at the registration stuff even tho i added the auth on my firebase with email activated. Please help me :(

Comment: Not an Ionic user here, but I don't see any code that takes the value from `<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Email"></ion-input>` and puts that in the `email` variable. So you might want to have a look at [how to read the value from an input field in Ionic](https://www.google.com/search?q=ionic+how+to+read+value+from+input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use another dependencies and plugin.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication 
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/firebase-authentication
```

Your `signup.page.ts` need to be like this:

```
import { FirebaseAuthentication } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/firebase-authentication/ngx';


constructor(private firebaseAuthentication: FirebaseAuthentication) { }

...


this.firebaseAuthentication.createUserWithEmailAndPassword('test@gmail.com', '123')
  .then((res: any) => console.log(res))
  .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
```

Check the official documentation of [Firebase Authentication](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-authentication) from Ionic,
and plugin's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication#installation), to undestand how to configure your `google-services.json` and/or `GoogleService-Info.plist`, instead of to configure in `environment.ts`